# How do I check if a Django user exists in a many-to-many field?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Device` model that has a many-to-many relationship to the built-in `User` object of Django. I'd like to override `get_queryset()` so that it only returns `Device` objects associated with the logged-in user.

`models.py`:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    maintainers = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="devices",
    )
```

`admin.py`:

```
class DeviceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(maintainers=request.user)
```

However, this code still shows all `Device` objects in my views defined in `views.py`, even if it is not associated with the logged-in user.

I've also tried `maintainers__contains=request.user` but the problem persists. What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly filter the QuerySet?

Comment: Have you tried `maintainers__in=[request.user]`? Seems unnecessary, as I would expect your current code to work given the Django documentation.

Comment: @gallen I just tried it but it didn't work. All device objects show up still. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Unfortunate. Seeing as you have a related_name set on the `maintainers` field, what happens if you try returning `request.user.devices.all()`?

Comment: @gallen sorry, I misunderstood what `get_queryset()` does. The above code functions correctly.

Comment: Given your answer below, I would suggest editing your question to make it more clear you were looking for this filter to be applied to a view. As it is, it could be misconstrued as being related to the admin portion of Django. Plus, the edit will help the question's visibility for future users!

Comment: @gallen thank you for the suggestion! I've edited the question to reflect that I wanted the filter to apply to the views defined in `views.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly thought that `get_queryset()` would apply to all views within the Django application, including views defined in `views.py`. However overriding `get_queryset()` in `admin.py` only changes the view for the admin dashboard/console.

In this case, `qs.filter(maintainers=request.user)` correctly filters the device list in the admin console (if the user is a staff member and is allowed to access the admin console).

For anyone wishing to filter the model in `views.py`, add the following to your `views.py` file:

```
class DeviceView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Device.objects.filter(maintainers=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Why not `return self.request.user.device_set`?

Comment: @Pynchia good point! That works too. I just think my answer would be helpful to those who want to apply different filters.